# Find HTML Table header index

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to find .10,.20,.30 up to .50 In a table header.
The search parameters are base on a formula and will eventually determine what column to filter.
I found this snippet from a previous similar post, but when I insert my table, I would get no results.

What could be the correct way to find the correct table header?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').click(function() {
    $('td').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).text() == $('#lookup').val()) {
        console.log(index)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header" id="ecentric">
    <th style="width:8%;">Column</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Plate/saddle</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Beam Width</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">0</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">.10</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">.20</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">.30</th>
    <th style="width:8%;">.40</th>
    <th style="width:8%;">.50</th>

  </tr>
  <input type="text" id="lookup">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="search">
```

Comment: you're searching for `td`s but your HTML has none. Is it supposed to be `th`?

Comment: Also remember that even if you fix that part, `$('th').each` will find _every_ `th` element on your page, not just all `th` elements in your table, so if you have multiple tables on your page (or if you add more in the future) you have a new problem. Keep your selectors specific (in this case: `#myTable th`).

Comment: What means exactly *"I need to find .10,.20,.30 up to .50 In a table header"* what about ***finding*** those? Do you need to select those cells? Get the values? And why your title states differently: *"Find HTML Table header index"* ?!

Comment: PS: `<input>` is an invalid child of `<table>`. Please, when creating snippets try to create correct markup as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add thead
2. Search for th instead of td
3. Cache the selected THs
4. Be more specific with your selectors, use `$('#myTable thead th')` instead of `$('th')` since you might target unwanted `TH` Elements in your DOM
5. You can even skip the first 3 using

   ```
    $('#myTable thead th:nth-child(n+3)')
      ...
      if (index !=-1) console.log(index+3)
   ```

```js
$(function() {
  const $ths = $('#myTable thead th');
  $('#search').on("click", function() {
    $ths.each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).text() == $('#lookup').val()) {
        console.log(index)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header" id="ecentric">
      <th style="width:8%;">Column</th>
      <th style="width:20%;">Plate/saddle</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Beam Width</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">0</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">.10</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">.20</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">.30</th>
      <th style="width:8%;">.40</th>
      <th style="width:8%;">.50</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<input type="text" id="lookup">
<input type="button" id="search" value="search">
```

Comment: And of course as one last improvement, since we're not updating the table it probably doesn't make a lot of sense to query for those `th` elements or the lookup every single time, we can just query for them once, prior to setting up the search listener.